# Nuget Install BLE.NET package fail. (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, nuget

I am implementing an APP with Xamarin.

Now I need to add Bluetooth function into it.

When trying to install BLE.NET package. I got the following error.

```
Could not install package 'ble.net 1.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How could I solve this? Should I change anything at screenshot below?

How should I analysis what would be the side effect if I changed anything at here?

[image]

Comment: You need to update your project to use .NET Standard.  PCL is very outdated.

Comment: netstandard2.0 is the way to go

Comment: In the net standard section. I only have ver1.0~1.5 to select. What should I do to make 2.0 selectable? And how should I figure what would be affected by changing the option? I am afraid that change this would make lots of side effect.

Comment: To upgrade your project, I recommend you to check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825824/how-do-i-convert-a-pcl-to-a-net-standard-library